# Named range pick up different rows when merged cells

Tags: excel

I have two named ranges that I want to use in a concatenate formula. The first named range is called `Phase01Names` and it is in `E6:E7` and contains Task 01 and Task 02. The second named range is `Phase01Hours` and it is in `AA6:AA7` and it contains the corresponding hours for each task.

[image]

On another sheet, in **merged** cells `B6:B38` (see picture below), I am trying to use the formula `=Phase01Names&" - "&Phase01Hours&CHAR(10)&Phase01Names&" - "&Phase01Hours`. I would like it to pick up both of the task names and hours, but it only picks up the first task (from row 6). How can I make it pick up both Task 01 from row 6 and Task 02 from row 7 in the named ranges and make it show like in the picture, but show both tasks, not just the first one.

The reason I need to use named ranges is because I want the user to be able to add more task names and hours, and still have the formula pick up all of them.

In the picture, it should say *Task 01 - 1* and then on the next line *Task 02 - 52*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Office365, the new TEXTJOIN function can help. On your second sheet, can you split B6 into two cells, one for the text and the other for the numbers?

If so, you'd then just set "Wrap" on each cell to true and add the following formulas...

In the first cell:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,Phase01Names
```

In the second cell:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,Phase01Hours)
```

You can use an array formula to combine the two into one cell by holding down Ctrl-Shift when you hit enter on the following formula...

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,Phase01Names & Phase01Hours)
```

...which will results in...

```
{=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,Phase01Names & Phase01Hours)}
```

This will give you exactly what you're looking for but array formulas can trip up other users.

For the sanity of anyone else looking at this, here's a simple example:
[image]

If you are comfortable using array formulas, you could instead do the following, being sure to hold down Ctrl-Shift when you hit enter...
[image]